# Rails how to post data to another controller from another model's form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, routes

So I have the models contract and employee. And from an employee's show html I want to be able to add a contract for that particular employee.

Here is the line from my show html

```
<%= link_to 'Add Contract', new_contract_path(@employee) %>
```

and my create function in contracts controller

```
def create
  puts "HERE IS"
  puts params[:id]
  puts "END"
  #create contract here for employee
end
```

**EDIT**

After farhan's suggestions this is now what my code looks like

```
def new
 @contract = Employee.find_by_id(params[:employee_id]).contracts.new
end
def create
 @employee = Employee.find_by_id(params[:employee_id])
 @contract = Employee.find_by_id(params[:employee_id]).contracts.build(contract_params)
 ...
end
```

my new.html

```
<h1>New Contract</h1>
<%= render 'form', contract: @contract%>
<%= link_to 'Back', employee_contracts_path(employee_id: @employee) %>
```

and my _form.html

```
<%= form_for(contract) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

but if i got to the url `empoyees/1/contracts/new` rails says
[image]

routes [image]

Answer (score 0):

Run `rake routes` in your terminal and you will see that `new_contract_path(@employee)` it is looking for a form with action `new` after submitting that form, it goes to `create` action. Also, if you want nested routes then it should be

```
resources :employees do
  resources :contracts
end
```

and you need to create a form named `new.html.erb`.

**Update**

After updating your `routes.rb`, your path helpers will change too,

in your view,

```
<%= link_to 'Add Contract', new_employee_contract_path(employee_id: @employee) %>
```

in your controller,

```
def create
  #assuming Employee has_many contracts
  contract = Employee.find_by_id(params[:employee_id]).contracts.build(contract_params)
  if contract.save
    #success case
  else
    #failure
  end
end

def new
  @contract = Employee.find_by_id(params[:employee_id]).contracts.new
end

private

def contract_params
  #permit required params
end
```

Comment: I have the html form for the new contract, I am able to access it properly from the link in the previous show, it shows up. It actually creates a contract, after submitting the form, but my problem is the @employee that I tried to pass was not in the contracts controller therefore I wasn't able to link my contract to the particular employee.

Comment: that's the reason I told you, you will need nested routes, check updated answer

Comment: Thank you I'm starting to understand now, I did what you said above but I encountered a new error. The form used to build the contract no longer knows who it is for, what would the new argument for `form_for` look like?

Comment: In your new action, `@contract = Employee.find_by_id(params[:employee_id]).contracts.new`

Comment: why you have 2 `new` actions? and `contract_params` should not be used for `new`. As I told you, your routes have changed, it will be now `employee_contracts_path(employee_id: @employee)` you need to have `@employee` set. in your terminal, type `rake routes` and post in question if this doesn't work either

Comment: added images, I did what you said and changed all the routes in my contract view to properly match the updated routes but the problem still remains.

Comment: You need to pass both resources to it as an array.. `form_for([@employee, contract])`

Comment: Just tried this too but still the same error pops up. Is there any other thing to do besides changing the path names when you nest a route? I'm not really familiar with it so I may not have done it